# InputStream null pointer when changing os from linux to windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, null, inputstream

How do you fix the problem of getting a null pointer exception from a file using an inputStream when changing from operations systems.
e.g.

```
InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
reader.readLine();
```

Fine on linux, breaks on windows 10.

Comment: File should be in resources folder. Are you using tomcat? Is it a unit test?

Comment: It is a unit test, but I do have the file in both my test resources and my project package. I have had the tests fully working before I changed os.

Comment: Should be under resources folder

Comment: do I have the change the path to something like "/resources/example.txt"?

Comment: I remember having the problem before and for windows I was suppose to add something like "::", but I have completely forgotten so here I am asking

Comment: pls check if your tree looks like this src/test/resources/example.txt and the test is in src/test/java/your/package/Test.java

Comment: Yes it does, theyre all branched from src. More specifically it is. src/test/resources. Note that my method calling it, is not in my test package.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `/` in your path.
In Linux, as paths starts in `/`, it's considered an absolute path. However, in Windows, where you usually start at `C:/` or whatever letter you use in your hard drive, that path doesn't exist.

So, don't start paths with `/` if you want to port your app between Linux an Windows, as they are treated as absolute paths. Use instead relative paths of your application.

Comment: that actually should not matter when loading a resource